# How to have multiple Applications inside one Web Site in IIS7 and set a Host Name for each App?

Tags: .net, iis-7, dns

my team and I have developed a suite of apps for our company and we host these on a server using IIS7. We are hosting all of our apps inside the "Default Web Site" as we want to use one IP and Port 80. We have been using our apps like this for a while but we know want to set up the DNS so that instead of accessing each app as "servername"."domain".com/"appName" we can do something like "appName"."domain".com and get the app's default page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself after a long while as no answer was provided and it was really an easy one...

We couldn't do what we were trying to do as it was simply incorrect to begin with. What we needed to do instead was we created multiple "web sites" in IIS all pointing to the same ip/port but with different host names. The thing with these http bindings is that you can repeat the type, IP address and Port if you provide different host names. Once we did that the sites started working like a charm.